# Error with terminal command sox in Xcode C++ system()

Tags: c++, xcode, unix, sox

Trying to run this code:

```
    system ( "sox play -n synth 1.0 tri  1000.0" );
```

and get such error:

```
    sh: sox: command not found
```

While executing this command in terminal all works fine (I have already installed sox).

Xcode clang c++17 macOS High Sierra 10.13

Comment: Did you try `system ( "/<full_path_to_sox>/sox play -n synth 1.0 tri  1000.0" );` already? Does that work? Also I think that the [tag:xcode] tag is probably completely irrelevant here. Check how `PATH` looks like in your code (use `getenv()`).

Comment: Yes, but there is another error then: "/usr/local/bin/sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `play': No such file or directory"; Here is what getenv() returned: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
"

Comment: Try `which sox` in your terminal to see which command is actually being run.

Comment: I've tried, but all seems to be normal in terminal.

Comment: @DamirovEldar `Here is what getenv() returned: ...` Try adding `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable in one of your `.rc` scripts.

Comment: Still getting the same error.